# Django / Python: Calculate total amount of item in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How do I calculate totals in a django template?

Let's say I want to generate a bill of customer's orders, something like:

I have following data:

```
obj = [{"location": "name", "timeSlot": '09:30 PM', "price": 2}, {"location": "name", "timeSlot": '09:30 PM', "price": 1}, {"location": "name", "timeSlot": '09:30 PM', "price": 3}, {"location": "name", "timeSlot": '09:30 PM', "price": 2}, {"location": "name", "timeSlot": '09:30 PM', "price": 4}]
```

Desired Report Output

```
 --------------------
        09:30 PM
  --------------------
    1   name   $ 2
    2   name   $ 1
    3   name   $ 3
    4   name   $ 4
------------------------
    Total      $ 10
```

Comment: The template is not the appropriate place to do this: the view is. What is the source of that data? Is it coming from a model query? If so, please show it.

Comment: Data is pass in arg in json format to html template. i.e  args['obj'] = orderList

Comment: That's not what I asked. Where is it coming from?

Comment: yeah, data is coming from model query--                                                  orders=order.objects.filter(id=timeslot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template is not the right place to do this. You should do it either in your view or model. For example, after you get your orders, you can do something like this:

```
orders=order.objects.filter(id=timeslot)
total = 0
for order in orders:
    total += order['price']

return render(request, 'your_template', {'orders': orders, 'total': total})
```

Now, total will be available in your template together with orders

Comment: I believe it must be ' total += order.price '

Answer (score 0):

I used custom filter for that.

Here is my customFilter.py code

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def slotTotalAmount(arg):
    return sum(d.get('price') for d in arg)
```

Its my django template code

```
{% load custom_filters %}
<span class="pull-left" ><b>Total</b></span>
<span class="pull-right"><b>{{Obj|slotTotalAmount|floatformat:0}}</b></span>
```

Its pretty easy to write one and give same output in both cases i.e. written in view.py and customFilter.py .